# Explorer.exe uses up all my RAM

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

So I download a web page video game player. And I think it infected my system with a fake explorer.exe that uses from 100,000k RAM to 5,000,000k RAM. I have done everything in my power to get remove the virus. I have run anti virus programs and even run them in safe mode. Nothing has helped. If anyone have any ideas, please help me. Thank you.

Edit 1-1-2015

After removing Adobe Flash 15. The usage of RAM was down sized.

Comment: Have you tried Malwarebytes Anti-malware? Also, what happens if you end the explorer process thats using so much memory?

Comment: Just for future reference look up VirtualBox (vbox). It is excellent to have throw-away Windows evaluation version installed for testing any download. Vbox has limitations regarding hardware access and some more, but my point is if you think your download/install is a risky one try it on Windows in vbox first, and give the download/install some time to show its true colors. I personally cannot imagine anymore to function without vbox, used as one of my preferred security tools.

Comment: share a xperf Trace of the Memory usage **GROW**: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa

Comment: Is your edit meant to just provide more info but you still have the problem, or are you saying that solved the problem?  If it solved the problem, can you make that an answer (you're allowed to answer your own question)?

Answer (score -1):

**Open "msconfig.exe"**. This can be done by opening command prompt and typing msconfig [Enter] or simply searching your start menu.

**Go to the tab that says services**

Tick "Hide all Microsoft services" box

Then Click "Disable all" button

[image]

**Go to Startup Tab**

Tick "Disable all"

[image]

Click the Ok button and restart the PC, see if anything changes.

You can use msconfig to reverse these changes at any time.

Furthermore: Find the location of the fake "explorer.exe", enter safemode, and delete it.