# windows10 explorer.exe uses to much memory

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-explorer

I upgraded my OS from win7 to win10, found that the **explorer.exe** will use to much memory when keeping the OS running for days, like this:
[image]

I've read this q&a: [Explorer.exe uses up all my RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/859059/explorer-exe-uses-up-all-my-ram), and I don't think my *explorer.exe* are fake processes due to malwares or viruses.

I've checked the **dll**s attached to explorer.exe using *process explorer* and the result is pasted here: http://codepad.org/xZ3LGHFe, but sorry I don't know how to check which dll is truly memory consuming (maybe the **"mapped size"** in the property page?)

So anyone could help me find out how to solve the problem (other than simply close the processes or even restart)?

### EDIT

Following the advices of @magicandre1981, I've captured and uploaded the ETL files(with PDBs): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vahSr3aGadU1pHY0h6TDBnV3M/view?usp=sharing （ETL rar）
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vahSr3aGadelpXSko5WGx3LW8/view?usp=sharing (PDBs rar)
hope this info could help someone with debugging.

Comment: Look at the details tab (second from right in my English view) instead of processes (流程). Nothing in your image seems exceptionally high; perhaps you have very low RAM to start with.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk which als runs since Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select First Level, CPU usage, VirtualAlloc usage, Resident Analysis and click start Now capture 1-2 minutes of the memory usage of Explorer and click on Save to store the report into an ETL file. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze it to see what Explorer is doing

Comment: have you captured the trace of the memory usage grow? Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: @magicandre1981, thx for your advice, I'd like to follow it, yet now after I end those processes, this issue cannot be replicated in short time... may I post you the analyzation files when I can replicate the issue (it may need the OS run a few more days)?

Comment: ok, post the files if you have the issue again.

Comment: @magicandre1981, hi I've uploaded the ETL file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vahSr3aGadM1BYN0x6R0RGUWM/view?usp=sharing , and the NGENPDB folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vahSr3aGadelpXSko5WGx3LW8/view?usp=sharing, do you have time to help me check it? (only 1day left for win10 free update o(╯□╰)o)

Comment: @magicandre1981, sorry the above link of ETL is uncompressed(900MB), here's the zipped version: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vahSr3aGadU1pHY0h6TDBnV3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in the trace the memory usage of the Explorer is only 80MB. I can see that you still run an old Win10 version (10586.122), update to 10586.494 with KB3172985 and look if you still see it again.

Comment: were you able to repro the high usage and capture it? Last time the usage was low

Comment: @magicandre1981, I was recently frequently rebooting my os due to upgrading, I'll paste again once the issue comes up ;)

Comment: besides, win10 is slow if I upgrade it from win7 directly. I upgraded my win7 at home and suffered, and then cured myself by **reset** the os, it's now fast~